# memory alignment into structure - alignment size equal to largest member size

Tags: c++, c, memory-alignment

I would like to know why we must take, for the alignment size of a structure, an alignment size equal to the largest member size into a structure.

Example :

```
struct MixedData
{
    char Data1;
    short Data2;
    int Data3;
    char Data4;
};
```

If we take the largest member `(int Data3)`, alignment is 4 bytes, so we have to do:

```
struct MixedData  /* After compilation in 32-bit x86 machine */
{
    char Data1; /* 1 byte */
    char Padding1[1]; /* 1 byte for the following 'short' to be aligned on a 2 byte boundary 
                         assuming that the address where structure begins is an even number */
    short Data2; /* 2 bytes */
    int Data3;  /* 4 bytes - largest structure member */
    char Data4; /* 1 byte */
    char Padding2[3]; /* 3 bytes to make total size of the structure 12 bytes */
};
```

But why don't I have, after `char Data1`, `char Padding1[3]` so `short Data2` begins at `adress(Data1) + 4` instead of `char Data1[1]`?

And, with the same logic, why don't I have `short Padding3[1]` after `short Data2`?

Another question: if I am on a 64 bits processor, I should use a 8 bytes alignement, so have I to set the following :

```
struct MixedData  /* After compilation in 64-bit x86_64 machine */
{
    char Data1; /* 1 byte */
    char Padding1[7]; /* 7 bytes */
    int Data3;  
    int Padding2[1]/* 4 bytes */
    char Data4; 
    char Padding3[7]; /* 7 bytes to make total size of the structure 24 bytes */
};
```

?

so total size 24 bytes is a multiple of 8 bytes ?

Comment: Padding is normally done to 'naturally' align a field. That is, a dword field is dword-aligned, a word field is word-aligned, and so on. There is no penalty for accessing, say, a word-sized field that is not dword aligned (but word aligned).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: that should have been posted as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OVERALL alignment of the structure should be that of the element with the greatest alignment requirement. This is required for the purpose of ensuring that, for example, an array of structures is always aligned. If you didn't have that, the size of `struct { int x; char c; };` would have the first element aligned, but the next three would have `x` unaligned.

It is often possible to convince the compiler to generate a "packed" data structure (with no alignment padding) and use that to get a packed array, but it's a bad idea to use that in all but very special cases, because at best it's slower, at worst it causes execution to stop due to "unaligned access trap" in the processor.

If the size of `int` is four bytes [it is for all compilers I'm aware of - `long` is either 4 or 8 bytes, depends on the compiler], both on a 32- and 64-bit (at least x86) will be 4 byte aligned.

If you want to have a 7 byte "gap" in a struct, this would work:

```
struct X { 
   char c;
   uint64_t x;
};
```

which would of course have:

```
struct X { 
   char c;
   char padding[7]; 
   uint64_t x;
};
```